# Is it no longer possible to use YouTube anonymously whilst being logged in to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account, login

I just noticed that, while being logged in to Gmail (e.g. having a Gmail tab open), I am also automatically logged in to YouTube. This did not happen before. I used to have my Gmail open whilst navigating YouTube "anonymously". Suddenly, this seems to be no possible anymore. And, if I log out of YouTube, I am immediately logged out of Gmail.

Is this an issue specific to me? Or are you also experiencing this change? Has there been a change in Google rules recently about this? I see that the [last change](https://policies.google.com/terms) to the ToS happened on the 22nd of January of 2019. Yet, I just noticed this change this week.

Update: my YouTube account is actually empty (I have never used it, not even to comment). So I deleted it (it seems what I deleted was a "brand" associated with my Gmail account). Now I can navigate YouTube anonymously, as before. Still, this doesn't really answer the question of whether something changed. And, if this is a more general issue other people face, deleting the YouTube account is clearly an extreme solution.

Update 2: I use Firefox.

Comment: Anecdotally, my experience is that if you "log in" to Google *whatever* in a browser etc. that "log in" will often carry over to other Google services. This isn't 100% true all the time (some situations apparently warrant Google confirming your identity i.e. making you retype your password) but it seems not uncommon (at least when I notice it).

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe is the standard/default behaviour of Google Account across all major browsers. The things could get mixed up for you between April 2nd - April 16th, 2019 when Google discontinued several of its platforms/services (Google+ etc.) and YouTube account might have been triggered as active if it was not priorly declared as deleted/deactivated with Google+.

Answer (score 0):

[This may be the feature that Chrome 69 bought in](https://gizmodo.com/google-chrome-is-now-quietly-forcing-you-to-log-in-here-1829265681).

You can disable it at chrome://flags/#account-consistency

Comment: Thanks. I use Firefox though. I don't see an equivalent feature in the most recent release notes, but it might be related to my last update of firefox.